# Filezilla Server does not accept UNC paths as virtual directory

Tags: filezilla

I have installed Filezilla Server Pro Enterprise 1.6.7 on a Windows 2016 Server to be able to offer sftp connections.
Everything works fine **but I am not able to set a virtual path for a user or group which is an UNC path** (\\servername\share\directory).
I am  using standard ports 21 and 22 and there is no firewall between the client and the server.
Filezilla server runs with local system account but is configured to use an admin user for filesystem access.
The <system user> is not enabled.
The Filezilla user's mount paths are set up this way:

```
    /          E:\Data
    /test      D:\
    /archtest  \\10.200.1.66\Archiv
```

An additional path on group level is

```
    /unctest   \\10.200.1.66\archiv
```

The access to the root is ok, the access to the D:\ drive as virtual directory \test is ok, but the virtual directories \archtest and \unctest will not be read. The message always is

```
    Couldn't open the file or directory (when connection via passive FTP)
    or
    No such file or directory.
    Error code: 2
    Error message from server (English): LSTAT error (when connection via SFTP)
```

I have tried any combination of user, path setting (name, ip, slash, backslash ...) etc. I could think of. No change in appearance, always the same results.

The access level of the unc share is already set to "everybody", the access is possible without problems in explorer and in any cmd.exe..

I really hope somebody will have seen this before and has a solution.

Comment: Have you made sure that the user the Filezilla Server is running under is allowed access to the UNC share?

Comment: why is the native ftp not been used and instead a enduser Software?

Comment: @Zac67 question is on point. To that, I must add another one: are the shares protected by password and login? In that case, FZPES has currently no way to allow access to those. The functionality is planned for the future. 

In any case, there's the official support forum you can refer to. You should have gotten a link when you bought the product.

Comment: Regarding access to the shares: "Filezilla server runs with local system account but is configured to use an admin user for filesystem access." I also had the FZ service run under a named admin account with no effect on the subject either. But getting Fabio right, password protected shares are not able to be used as virtual directories, even when shared for "everybody" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filezilla Server usually runs as a service - that service needs to have access to the UNC paths. FZ Server has no provisions for authenticating on its own.

The default *Local System* account allows no access to network resources. You'd need to change the service to run under a dedicated user account and grant that account access to the network share.

If you're not using domain accounts you might need to log that dedicated user into the console session, access the share saving user credentials and then restart FZS.

Beware that updating Filezilla Server may revert the service account back to *Local System*, so it might need repair afterwards.

Comment: changing the user FZ Server logs on with does the trick. The share is now accessible. Sorry, I am not able to upvote the answer (to little reputation on this site).

Comment: It is worth to mention that the option to set a user for file access in the "Rights Management" area in the configuration does not work in this case. The only way to access the UNC paths was to set the user the service is running under.